# Declaring variables before "{}" using ":" in class constructer

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I've been flipping through the SFML blueprints book to start getting my feet wet in graphics. I noticed in one of their code examples in their game class constructor:

```
Game::Game() : _window(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "SFML Title") {
     code code code...
}
```

The **_window(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "SFML Title")** being placed before the {}, not inside. Is this bad practice? What is doing this called? I'm still new to c++ but I haven't come across something like this yet.

Comment: It's good practice, it's called [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this bad practice?

No, it's good practice. If the member is `const` qualified type or reference type, it's the only way to initialize that member in constructor.

> What is doing this called?

It's called [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Answer (score 1):

That's called a member initialization list. They're part of the C++ language. A member initialization list allows you to initialize members during class initialization. One reason why they're  good practice is because they allow you to initialize `const` members when assigning won't work. For example, the following class definition won't work because `const int member1` wasn't initialized with a value, nor can you assign to a `const int` because `const` makes it read-only.

```
class Game{
private:
    const int member_var; //won't work, needs to be initialized
    int member_var2;
public:
    Game() {} //Game constructor
};
```

With initialization lists, you're able to initialize `const` members like these and other variables by adding a colon after your constructor definition (but before the brackets to define it) and initializing members as needed, either with direct initialization (using "()") or uniform initialization (using "{}"). To initialize multiple members, separate them with a comma.

```
class Game{
private:
    const int member_var; 
    int member_var2;
public:
    Game(): member_var(1), member_var2(2) {} 
    //Uniform initialization is ": member_var{1}, member_var{2}" 
};
```

In your example, the `Game()` constructor was defined outside the class definition (likely in another .cpp file) via `Game::Game()` with a member initialization list. I'm guessing `_window` is a class with one constructor that takes `sf::VideoMode(800,600)` and  `"SFML Title"` as arguments.